# Three.js Render not getting cleared after using ImmediateRenderObject

Tags: three.js, shader, marching-cubes

I am trying to mask a 3D scene with another 3D scene. I managed to get it working with regular THREE.Mesh objects as shown below:

[image: Mask working]

The main scene has a bunch of low poly spheres. The mask scene has a red cube. Both scenes are passed as textures to a custom shader that checks the red pixels on the mask and draws the pixels of the main.

It works. Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/at4rumn6/3/

```
// please check source on jsfiddle
```

--

However, if I replace the bunch of spheres by blobs like in the [Marching Cubes](http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_marchingcubes) example, it stops working. The problem is shown below:

[image: Mask error]

It seems like something is not getting cleared in the renderer. It might be related to [THREE.ImmediateRenderObject](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/5c7e0df9b100ba40cdcaaf530196290e16c34858/src/extras/objects/ImmediateRenderObject.js), but I don't understand what it is doing. This seems like a very specific case, I might have found a limitation in the library. Or maybe I'm just doing something wrong.

Here is another fiddle showing the error: http://jsfiddle.net/Lwm93rxr/2/

Is there a way to clear the buffer and get my mask working without any 'dirt' from other scenes?

Comment: THREE.WebGLRenderer 71, Chrome 43, Mac OS X Yosemite

Comment: Opened issue on github https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/6783

Answer (score 0):

The discussion continued in the GitHub issues and this has been fixed: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/6783